# Ошибка в параметре запроса aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как правильно передать json в запрос?

```
async def gather_with_concurrency(n):
    with open('url_header.json') as f:
        url_header = json.load(f)
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, headers=url_header)

    async def get(url):

        date1 = str(datetime.now().timestamp()).split('.')[0]
        date2 = str(datetime.now().timestamp() - int(4600)).split('.')[0]
        json_data = {
            "operationName": "catalogProductsBoard",
            "variables": {
                # 'sort': 'DATE_PUBLISHED_DESC',
                "sort": "DEFAULT",
                "attributes": [{
                    "slug": "price",
                    "value": None,
                    "from": int(200000),
                    "to": int(9000000)
                }, {
                    "slug": "categories",
                    "value": ["detskaya-odezhda"],
                    "from": None,
                    "to": None
                }],
                "datePublished": {
                    "to": int(date1),
                    "from": int(date2)

                },
                "location": {
                    "latitude": None,
                    # 'longitude': 158.63197429459169,
                    "longitude": None,
                    "city": "576d061ad53f3d80945f995a",
                    # 'distanceMax': None,
                },
                "search": "",
                "cursor": "",
            },
            "extensions": {
                "persistedQuery": {
                    "version": 1,
                    "sha256Hash": "bf7a22ef077a537ba99d2fb892ccc0da895c8454ed70358c0c7a18f67c84517f",
                },
            },
        }
        async with semaphore:
            async with session.get(url, ssl=False, params=json_data) as response:
                obj = json.loads(await response.read())
                print(obj)
                results.append(obj)

    await asyncio.gather(*(get(url) for url in urls))
    await session.close()
```

При отправке запроса выдается ошибка

```
"TypeError: Invalid variable type: value should be str, int or float, got
{'sort': 'DEFAULT', 'attributes': [{'slug': 'price', 'value': None, 'from': 200000, 'to': 9000000}, {'slug': 'categories', 'value': ['detskaya-odezhda'], 'from': None, 'to': None}], 'datePublished': {'to': 1653380390, 'from': 1653375790}, 'location': {'latitude': None, 'longitude': None, 'city': '576d061ad53f3d80945f995a'}, 'search': '', 'cursor': ''} of type <class 'dict'>
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001E8C5FB5400>"
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что там используется get ? Нет стандарта для передачи сложного json (с вложенностями) в GET. может там POST. А вообще Json в виде питоновского словаря передается параметром json, а не params

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, а как передавать прокси в запрос?

Comment: документацию https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html не пробовали смотреть ? там вроде параметр proxy описан